# Windows Server 2012: Limiting number of users who can access a file at any given time

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am relatively new to server administration, and have been unable to find much information regarding this matter. I wish to have a file which numerous users have access to, but that allows only 1 user at any given time the ability to access it.

Example: User1 and User2 have read/write permission to the file, but if User1 is currently accessing the file, I do not want User2 to be able to access it until User1 has completed their work on it. Is this possible in a Windows Server 2012 environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the number of simultaneous users on a file share basis by going to the advanced properties of the share itself.  Not sure how well this would work though for what you are looking at.

[image]

This sounds like you want checkout / check-in capabilities which is possible with something like [Microsoft Sharepoint](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-sharepoint-collaboration-software-FX103479517.aspx).  There are probably other utilities that dont require that much infrastructure.  But Sharepoint does it fairly well.  With Sharepoint you can also have multiple versions / revisions of a file as well.